# Laravel - what is the different between exists validation rule and a normal query?

Tags: sql, laravel

What is the different between the validation rule [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists) and a custom rule that make a query to get the first record with the corresponding params in the database?

Are both the same or exists is faster and optimized?

Comment: Basically - no difference. As you could see in docs `exists` rule is nice shortcut.

Comment: Okay, is that what I want to know, I know that is so simple, but create an answer so this question don't stay unanswerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go deeper into documentation you'll see what is called there. 
You can find [`ValidatesAttributes`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.html) trait that holds related methods for these [rule](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.html#method_validateExists)s (you can check the rest of code in `Validation` namespace). In [code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L644) you can see it uses [Exists](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Exists.html) class called in [line 680](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L680).

So whether you use it as substring, array element or class it will eventually call and check against Exists class.